# Query documents with access control filter

Tags: elasticsearch

Each document in my Elasticsearch index has two access control lists containing user ids. One is an allow list, the other is a deny list. I am trying to add a filter to a given query that considers these ACLs. I thought I could use a `bool` query with a `must` clause for the given query, a `filter` clause for the allow list, and a `must_not` clause for the deny list. What I have so far (example for user 1):

```
{
"bool" : {
"must" : {
  [given query]
},
"filter" : [ {
  "match" : {
    "acl.allow" : {
      "query" : "/user/1",
      "type" : "boolean"
    }
  }
}],
"must_not" : [ {
  "match" : {
    "acl.deny" : {
      "query" : "/user/1",
      "type" : "boolean"
    }
  }
}]
}
}
```

Unfortunately, this query does not return the desired result. It returns objects that have not listed user 1 in their allow list (a behavior I don't understand). Also, it (obviously) ignores objects with empty access control lists (which should be visible to anyone). Any suggestions to fix that?

Comment: What's the mapping for the entire `acl` field and, also, please provide some sample documents especially for the `acl` fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. First of all, using `match` isn't really a good solution for that kind of query—due to its analyzer. Using `term` though left me puzzled why I did not get any results. Term queries only return results if the corresponding field is set to `not_analyzed`. Thus I changed my mapping:

```
"acl": {
        "properties": {
          "allow": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "deny": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
```

My second problem—treating objects with empty ACLs as visible to anyone—was solved using `exists` nested in `must_not` nested in `bool`. This is recommended as substitute for the deprecated `missing` query. My final query looks like this and passed all ACL related tests I could think of.

```
{
"bool" : {
"must" : {
  [given query]
},
"filter" : {
  "bool" : {
    "should" : [ {
      "terms" : {
        "acl.allow" : [ "/user/1" ]
      }
    }, {
      "bool" : {
        "must_not" : {
          "exists" : {
            "field" : "acl.allow"
          }
        }
      }
    } ]
  }
},
"must_not" : {
  "terms" : {
    "acl.deny" : [ "/user/1" ]
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Two things: 1. There is a `missing` filter that is effectively the same as `must_not` containing `exists`. 2. This is minor, but if you are not sending arrays to the acl queries, then you could change it to `term` and drop the usage of the `[ ]` array (as it just accepts a single term).

Comment: Thanks for the input! I use the java API where the `missing` filter is marked as deprecated. That's why I make use of `bool`/`must_not`/`exists` (as suggested in the java docs). Your objection concerning the use of arrays is 100% correct. However, in my case, a user may belong to one or more groups whose ids are sent alongside with the user id. It wasn't disclosed though, so you couldn't know. I tried to simplify my problem. :)